# Indexing column in Pandas Dataframe returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am running into a problem with trying to index my dataframe. As shown in the attached picture, I have a column in the dataframe called 'Identifiers' that contains a lot of redundant information ({'print_isbn_canonical': '). I only want the ISBN that comes after.

```
    #Option 1 I tried
    testdf2 = testdf2[testdf2['identifiers'].str[26:39]]
    
    #Option 2 I tried
    testdf2['identifiers_test'] = testdf2['identifiers'].str.replace("{'print_isbn_canonical': '","")
```

Unfortunately both of these options turn the dataframe column into a colum **only containing NaN values**

Please help out! I cannot seem to find the solution and have tried several things. Thank you all in advance!

[Example image of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNzGt.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean `testdf2['new']=testdf2['identifiers'].str[26:39]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contents of your column `identifiers` is a real dict / json type, you can use the string accessor `str[]` to access the dict value by key, as follows:

```
testdf2['identifiers_test'] = testdf2['identifiers'].str['print_isbn_canonical']
```

**Demo**

```
data = {'identifiers': [{'print_isbn_canonical': '9780721682167', 'eis': '1234'}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['isbn'] = df['identifiers'].str['print_isbn_canonical']

print(df)

                                                identifiers           isbn
0  {'print_isbn_canonical': '9780721682167', 'eis': '1234'}  9780721682167
```

Comment: I feel like the greatest of noobs right now. But it works!!!

Comment: Thanks! @AnuragDabas  I'm glad to co-work with you and other contributors in this big family here.  Great to learn from you and others too! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
testdf2['new_column'] = testdf2.apply(lambda r : r.identifiers[26:39],axis=1)
```

Here I assume that the identifiers column is string type

Comment: THank you for your very quick response! When i try your solution I get: 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

I tried looking up this error, and it seemed to state that the reason is that the column 'identifiers' is a dict? When I do dtype it says it's a pandas string column ('0'). Could you help out once more?